# Regex Match Multi-line

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a small bash script to edit my mkdocs config file and update a section of it based on the contents of another directory.

I am attempting to replace contents inside of the config file but I'm having some trouble matching the section I need to replace with a regex pattern.

Here is the section I am attempting to update:

```
# Pages
pages:
  - Home: index.md
  - Getting Started:
    - Installation: getting-started/installation.md
  - Methods:
    - config: methods/config.md
    - add_header: methods/add_header.md
    - add_tabs: methods/add_tabs.md
    - add_fields: methods/add_fields.md
    - footer: methods/footer.md
  - Settings Fields:
    - Text: fields/text.md
    - Checkbox: fields/checkbox.md
    - Radio: fields/radio.md
    - Select: fields/select.md
    - Image: fields/image.md
    - Multicheck: fields/multicheck.md
  - Hooks & Filters:
    - Overview: actions/overview.md
  - Examples:
    - Basic Plugin: examples/basic-plugin.md
    - Plugin Add-On: examples/plugin-addon.md
```

The section I am looking to update is the 'Settings Fields' section.

At the moment I have:

```
/ {2}- Settings Fields:([^#]+) {2}-/g
```

Which seems to match what I need, and then some.

eg:

```
    - Text: fields/text.md
    - Checkbox: fields/checkbox.md
    - Radio: fields/radio.md
    - Select: fields/select.md
    - Image: fields/image.md
    - Multicheck: fields/multicheck.md
  - Hooks & Filters:
    - Overview: actions/overview.md
  - Examples:
    - Basic Plugin: examples/basic-plugin.md
    -
```

Ideally, I would just like to have the following returned, so I can just remove it and replace it with the new contents:

```
- Text: fields/text.md
- Checkbox: fields/checkbox.md
- Radio: fields/radio.md
- Select: fields/select.md
- Image: fields/image.md
- Multicheck: fields/multicheck.md
```

I've setup a regex101 test, where I am fiddling with things, but I'm no regex wizard. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/DViAoA/1

Comment: Try [`(?m)^ {2}- Settings Fields:\s*\K[^#]+?(?=\R {2}-)`](https://regex101.com/r/Fldprq/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your regex to use an ungreedy operator and add the start of line for the `{2}` pattern, like this:

```
 {2}- Settings Fields:([^#]+?)^ {2}-
                ungreedy ---^ ^--- start of line
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZPJnF7/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that complex regex for this.
You just need what is between `Settings` and `Hooks`.
Edited to make it more flexible with pattern. It will now match to 2 space and a - or end of string.

```
$re ='/\s{2}-\sHooks & Filters:(.*?)^\s{2}-|\z/ms';
$str = '# Pages
pages:
 - Home: index.md
 - Getting Started:
   - Installation: getting-started/installation.md
  - Methods:
    - config: methods/config.md
    - add_header: methods/add_header.md
    - add_tabs: methods/add_tabs.md
    - add_fields: methods/add_fields.md
    - footer: methods/footer.md
  - Settings Fields:
    - Text: fields/text.md
    - Checkbox: fields/checkbox.md
    - Radio: fields/radio.md
    - Select: fields/select.md
    - Image: fields/image.md
    - Multicheck: fields/multicheck.md
  - Hooks & Filters:
     - Overview: actions/overview.md
  - Examples:
    - Basic Plugin: examples/basic-plugin.md
    - Plugin Add-On: examples/plugin-addon.md';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

Echo rtrim($matches[1]);
```

https://3v4l.org/5WrSY
https://regex101.com/r/DViAoA/2

Comment: Thanks @Andreas , this looks good - but the only problem is what I'm targeting might not always been the same section. I've got a function written where I pass the section to update, in this case 'Settings Fields'. So it may not always be the '- Hooks' that is the end. For example, I could pass in 'Hooks & Filters' to update that section, which 'Examples' would then be the limit.

Comment: Try it now with the new pattern.